# Anaconda python Error installation

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I am a new guy in programming in Python 2.7.5. I have just installed Anaconda though when I restarted my laptop I got the following error on the startup:
"C:\Users\Constantinos\Anaconda2\api-ms-win-core-synch-I1-2-0.DLL is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error.Try installing the program again using the  original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support."
I am running on Windows 7 64 bit. Any suggestions please?
Thanks

Comment: Follow the suggestion of the error message and reinstall Anaconda? Where did you download Anaconda from? The Python version should not be that old...

Comment: Right,so your suggesting that I should download python 3.5?I got anaconda from:https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: No, Python 2.7 should be up to 2.7.13 now or something like that. Anyways, try reinstalling, see if it helps

Comment: Thanks that helped I installed 2.7.13! Though when I start Python idle after installing anaconda and typing import matplotlib it shows an error that there is no such module how can I fix that?

Comment: Do you have multiple installations of Python?

Comment: No but is it possible that anaconda 's setup reinstalls another installation of Python?

Comment: Yes, try uninstalling everything, then installing only one version

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try it!

Comment: Sry again I try reinstalling everything and I get the following when I start anaconda navigator

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Constantinos\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 75, in exception_handler
return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Constantinos\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py",

Comment: line 108, in start_app
if misc.load_pid() is None: # A stale lock might be around
File "C:\Users\Constantinos\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\misc.py", line 384, in load_pid
cmds = process.cmdline()
File "C:\Users\Constantinos\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 701, in cmdline
return self._proc.cmdline()
File "C:\Users\Constantinos\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 623, in wrapper
raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._name)
AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=4492)

Comment: Please try running `conda clean -l` in the Anaconda prompt, and run it in an elevated command prompt if necessary